# Behaviour of Erlang system_info and system_flag methods

Tags: erlang, elixir

Are these methods `system_info` and `system_flag` make a system call to the Operating system each time I call one of them? Or are they use stored values of Erlang virtual machine?

Task: I'm writing an application which checks the idling processors and create new processes to complete a task. If these methods are doing a system call, it can be a performance overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions system_info and system_flag are BIF's which make calls to the c code found in the file erl_bif_info.c , this code is not a NIF so calling them will not cause problems in the sense that long running NIFs might.

NIFs are considered harmful

- Long-running NIFs will take over a scheduler and prevent Erlang from
  efficiently handling many processes.
- Short-running NIFs will still confuse the scheduler if they take more
  than a few microseconds to run.

A crashing NIF will take down your VM.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on nifs. When is it a good idea to use them? I regularly use a nif based json parser. Am I making a wrong choice then?

Comment: The problem is that JSON is a highly inefficient data structure (similar in inefficiency to XML, although perhaps not as bad). If you can avoid using JSON, you probably should. MessagePack can replace it in many situations.

Comment: I think you are dithering slightly here. `system_info` and `system_flag` are **NOT** NIFs in the sense you mean. NIFs are very useful if used correctly. The time limit when they start to impose on the system is **MILLI** seconds not microseconds. The OTP team is of course working on a solution to this which will make the problem go away, dirty schedulers.

Comment: @rvirding thanks for your explanation i always thought BIF's written in C are optimized NIF's for the erlang VM.

Answer (score 3):

The functions `erlang:system_info` and `erlang:system_flag` inspect and work on the Erlang virtual machine and not the underlying OS. They allow you to inspect the system to see how it is performing and in some ways to control it. The BEAM, the erlang virtual machine, is a complex beast and there is a lot of information to be had. Another useful function is `process_info` which allows you to get information about one process.

While these functions are obviously written in C you can be certain that calling them will not casue problems in the sense that long running NIFs might. Long-running in the case means more than milliseconds. Also important is how often they are called and whether by the same process etc.